# Change div to visible after initial load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where a div is loaded before the javascript, which displays the text, and after the javascript is loaded it will display it differently (autoscrolling). To prevent this I tried adding `visibility: hidden;` to the div `#vs`, and then add the following code to the jQuery `document.getElementById("vs").style.visibility= "visible";`

This solves the problem, but after 3 seconds it will disappear, and after 3 seconds it will reappear, and it keeps going like this. How do I prevent this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function autoRefresh() {
    $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        // Find div id #vs
        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
        $('div#vs').html(result);

        document.getElementById("vs").style.visibility= "visible";
        // If div id #vs takes up more than 85% of inner height, add class .vscroll
        if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight > window.innerHeight * 0.85)
          $('div#vs').addClass('vscroll');
        // If div id #vs takes up less than 85% of inner height, remove class .vscroll
        if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight < window.innerHeight * 0.85)
          $('div#vs').removeClass('vscroll');
      }
    });
  }
  autoRefresh();
  // Refresh at page load and every 3000 milliseconds / 3 seconds
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(autoRefresh, 3000);
})
```

Comment: Well you are refreshing the page every 3 seconds, which probably explains it. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I need to refresh the div #vs every 3 seconds to check for changes, without refreshing the whole page. This part works well, just not together with the latest addition, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't really using XHR to retrieve data from a **URL**? Also, you should use jQuery's `.load()` method. It was designed to remove all this pain.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how to change to this?

Comment: Where does `data` come from and what does it contain in the `success` handler? As written, you are not retrieving any data from anywhere.

Comment: I really don't know, I got help with that part! What can I remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a JQuery expert, but I think it's because you are using `getElementById()` instead of a JQuery selector.

I think you need to do this:

`$('div#vs').attr('style','visibility: visible');`

Forgive me if the JQuery code isn't perfect, I haven't tried to run it

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!